# perl IPC:Open3 minimal to pass perlcritic?

Tags: perl, perl-critic, ipcopen3

I am reading the perlcritic documentation to avoid backticks and use IPC::Open3 here:

http://perl-critic.stacka.to/pod/Perl/Critic/Policy/InputOutput/ProhibitBacktickOperators.html

I am trying to find the least verbose option that will work and satisfy perlcritic:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3 'open3'; $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
my $cmd = 'ls';
my ($w,$r,$e); open3($w,$r,$e,$cmd);
my @o = <$r>; my @e = <$e>;
1;
```

But it complains with the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in <HANDLE> at ipc_open3.pl line 7
```

Any ideas?

EDITED: Ok, here is what I've got. Unless there is a way to simplify it, I'll stick to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3 'open3'; $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
use Symbol 'gensym';
my $cmd = 'ls';
my ($w,$r,$e) = (undef,undef,gensym); my $p = open3($w,$r,$e,$cmd);
my @o = <$r>; my @e = <$e>;
1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error parameter to `IPC::Open3::open3` should not be undefined. The [synopsis for `IPC::Open3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3#SYNOPSIS) uses the `Symbol::gensym` function to pre-initialize the error argument:

```
my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
use Symbol 'gensym';
$err = gensym;
$pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err, 'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
```

The input and output parameters can be replaced with autogenerated filehandles, so it is OK to pass `undef` for those arguments.

Of course the least verbose option to satisfy perlcritic here is

```
my @o = `ls 2>/dev/null`   ## no critic
```

Comment: The least verbose option is to ignore this critic when you want the error to appear on STDERR anyway!

Comment: `my @o = <$r>; my @e = <$e>;` can deadlock. They need to be replaced with IO::Select if you're going to keep using `open3`.

Answer (score 8):

The advice on that page is awful. IPC::Open3 is a low-level module that's hard to use. The very code the page suggests will hang (deadlock) if lots is sent to STDERR.

Use [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun3) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) instead.

Examples:

```
run3 $cmd, undef, \my $out, \my $err;
run3 [ $prog, @args ], undef, \my $out, \my $err;
run3 [ $prog, @args ], undef, \my @out, \my @err;
```

Comment: IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run don't seem to be in my corelist. I would rather stick to corelist for the moment. Is IPC::Cmd any good?